# What is the difference between using viewBinding and findViewById() when setting up a cast button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a cast button in a fragment that I'm initializing using the Cast SDK's built-in `CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton` function. When I call it like this:

```
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), viewBinding.contentButtonMediaroute);
```

it fails somehow and the button isn't clickable. When I switch it to this:

```
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getView().findViewById(R.id.content_button_mediaroute));
```

it works properly. From what I understand, `viewBinding` is supposed to be the better alternative to `findViewById`. Why isn't the first call working?

Comment: Please add the stack trace error message

Comment: Both give the same result. But try putting `findViewById<TYPE>(R.id` and share logcat for better understanding.

Comment: Same problem here? Did you find a solution?

Comment: I never did fix this